# Connecting to Azure Databricks from R using jdbc and sparklyr

Tags: r, azure, jdbc, databricks, sparklyr

I'm trying to connect my on-premise R environment to an Azure Databricks backend using sparklyr and jdbc. I need to perform operations in databricks and then collect the results locally. Some limitations:

1. No RStudio available, only a terminal
2. No databricks-connect. Only odbc or jdbc.

The configuration with odbc + dplyr is working, but it seems too complicated, so I would like to use jdbc and sparklyr. Also, if I use RJDBC it works, but it would be great to have the tidyverse available for data manipulation. For that reason I would like to use sparklyr.

I've the jar file for Databricks (DatabricksJDBC42.jar) in my current directory. I downloaded it from: https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download. This is what I got so far:

```
library(sparklyr)

config <- spark_config()
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-class-path` <- "./DatabricksJDBC42.jar"

# something in the configuration should be wrong
sc <- spark_connect(master = "https://adb-xxxx.azuredatabricks.net/?o=xxxx",
                    method = "databricks",
                    config = config)

spark_read_jdbc(sc, "table",  
  options = list(
  url = "jdbc:databricks://adb-{URL}.azuredatabricks.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/{ORG_ID}/{CLUSTER_ID};AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD={PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}",
  dbtable = "table",
  driver = "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver"))
```

This is the error:

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid method toDF for object 17/org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader fields 0 selected 0

My intuition is that the sc might not be not working. Maybe a problem in the master parameter?

PS: this is the solution that works via RJDBC

```
databricks_jdbc <- function(address, port, organization, cluster, token) {
    location <- Sys.getenv("DATABRICKS_JAR")
    driver <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver",
                          classPath = location)
    con <- DBI::dbConnect(driver, sprintf("jdbc:databricks://%s:%s/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/%s/%s;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=%s", address, port, organization, cluster, token))
con
}
```

DATABRICKS_JAR is an environment variable with the path "./DatabricksJDBC42.jar"

Then I can use DBI::dbSendQuery(), etc.

Thanks,

I Tried multiple configurations for master. So far I know that jdbc for the string "jdbc:databricks:..." is working. The JDBC connection works as shown in the code of the PS section.

Answer (score 0):

Configure R studios with azure databricks -> go to cluster -> app -> set up azure [Rstudio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sparkr/rstudio) .

[image]

For information refer this third party [link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/databricks-jdbc-r.rst) it has detail information about connecting azure databricks with R

> **Alternative approach in python**:

**Code:**

```
Server_name = "vamsisql.database.windows.net"
Database = "<database_name"
Port = "1433"
user_name = "<user_name>"
Password = "<password"
jdbc_Url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(Server_name, Port,Database)
conProp = {
  "user" : user_name,
  "password" : Password,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_Url, table="<table_name>", properties=conProp)
display(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The response is useful but I think it does not solve the original question. Looking for the mininal solution. Only a local terminal, no RStudio, and Sparklyr. It should be a solution available only via Databricks free tools and Azure.